# How to remove duplicate rows from excel import in Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I am importing an excel file in Laravel 7 that contains employees' records. The file has Columns Employee No. and date. There are duplicate rows that contain the same employee No. and date. I want to store only 1 such record and discard the duplicate rows. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [laravel-excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html), you can define rules for validation and check for duplicate records.

In below example, I've checked for duplication for user with email address.

```
class ModelImport implements ToModel, WithValidation
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            '1' => \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('users', 'email'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, add skipping errors by implementing `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure` interface as stated in [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html?#skipping-failures)

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class ModelImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure
{
    use Importable, SkipsFailures;
}
```